# Get the first occurance in a dictionary LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code where it keeps looping even after first occurrence in the code.  I want to stop but I cannot apply `Any` in my case

```
    public List<FieldConfiguration> GetListOfProvisionsForBenefits(Dictionary<int, string> benefits)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("SELECT ProvisionID ,BenefitID,ProvisionName, BPROV_Flags FROM BenefitProvisions WHERE");
        int intSQLvar = 0;
        string strSeperator = string.Empty;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> benefit in benefits)
        {

            sb.AppendFormat(" {0} BenefitID=@benerfit{1}", strSeperator, intSQLvar);
            intSQLvar++;
            strSeperator = "OR";
        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_strDBConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();
        intSQLvar = 0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> benefit in benefits)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(string.Format("@benerfit{0}", intSQLvar), SqlDbType.Int, 32).Value = benefit.Key.ToString();
            intSQLvar++;
        }

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
                con = null;
            }
        }
        List<ProvisionDetails> lstProvisions = new List<ProvisionDetails>();

        if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
                lstProvisions = (from r in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                select new ProvisionDetails()
                        {
                            ID = r.Field<int>("ProvisionID"),
                            Name = r.Field<string>("ProvisionName"),
                            BenefitID = r.Field<int>("ProvisionID"),
                            OptionValue =  r.Field<int>("ProvisionID") 
                        }).ToList();

            if (benefits.Count == 1)
            {
                return (from p in lstProvisions
                        select new FieldConfiguration()
                        {
                            Name = p.Name,
                            ProvisionFieldID = p.ID.ToString(),
                            FieldType = Configuration.SyncapayPlus.FieldType.Provision,
                            Caption = (from b in benefits 
                                           where(b.Key == p.BenefitID)
                                       select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)).ToString() // to do change caption  benefitname_provisionName
                        }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return (from p in lstProvisions.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Where(y => y.Count() > 1)
               .SelectMany(z => z)
                        select new FieldConfiguration()
                        {
                            Name = p.Name,
                            ProvisionFieldID = p.ID.ToString(),
                            FieldType = Configuration.SyncapayPlus.FieldType.Provision,
                            SourceOption = p.OptionValue.ToString(),
                            Caption =
                            (from b in benefits
                             where (b.Key == p.BenefitID)
                             select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)).ToString() // to do change caption  benefitname_provisionName
                        }).ToList();
            }


        }
        return null;

    }
```

I want to apply ANY in this section where I get the caption; when I find the first benefit I want it to exit and assign it:

```
Caption =
     (from b in benefits
     where (b.Key == p.BenefitID)
     select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)).ToString() // to do change caption  benefitname_provisionName
                           }).ToList();
            }
```

Comment: That's a really heavy query. Also, there's nothing in your query that says 'stop' (`Single()` / `First()`) - so it makes sense that it's not halting when it finds a matching item.

Comment: IMHO, you are doing WAY too much for a single query there. Think about what a pain debugging will be.

Comment: Well i can post my  complete function so you can see why am doing this

Comment: @Graham I am really stuck and have no idea how can i simplify it ..

Comment: Just dont try to do everything in one line. Set up some dummy collections, fill them, iterate over them, etc. Debugging will be easier. I am a HUGE fan of linq, but you are trying to do too much in one shot in that `else return...` chunk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know that there'll always be at least one such benefit - or you don't mind using a placeholder for a missing value - you can use something like this:

```
Caption = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
                        benefits.Where(b => b.Key == p.BenefitID)
                                .Select(b => b.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault(), // Or First
                        p.Name);
```

I'd advise you not to mix and match your query expressions and dot notation so much though - it's quite confusing at the moment.

Comment: I think it is time to clean up  do you think that i can simplify my queries here?

Comment: @lighty: I haven't looked through the code in enough detail to say - but I strongly suspect so, yes. Ideally you should do more of the work in the database, rather than in-memory.

Comment: @jon i was debating relaying on the db or do it this way!! Isn't it more efficient run one call the db and manipulate the data myself ?  I guess i looked at it from the wrong direction

Comment: @lighty: I would need to understand the query in more detail to say, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FirstorDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) here. (posting it as answer after my comment)

```
Caption = string.Format("{0}_{1}",
                        benefits.Where(b => b.Key == p.BenefitID)
                                .Select(b => b.Value)
                                .FirstOrDefault(), // Or First
                        p.Name);
```

it will return the first element of a sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that you are doing way too much here and it makes readability very difficult and therefore will make debugging and future maintainability very difficult.

However, to answer your question, you may want to try something along the following:

```
(from b in benefits
 where (b.Key == p.BenefitID)
 select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)).First()
```

or

```
 (from b in benefits
  where (b.Key == p.BenefitID)
  select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)).FirstOrDefault()
```

I believe the .ToString() would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your indentation and don't switch between the query syntax and the traditional syntax when it's not necessary. This will make it easier to spot and understand problems.

```
return (from p in lstProvisions
        group x by x.Name into y
        where y.Count() > 1
        from z in y
        select new FieldConfiguration()
          {
            Name = p.Name,
            ProvisionFieldID = p.ID.ToString(),
            FieldType = Configuration.SyncapayPlus.FieldType.Provision,
            SourceOption = p.OptionValue.ToString(),
            Caption = (from b in benefits
                       where b.Key == p.BenefitID
                       select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)
                      ).ToString()
          }
       ).ToList()
```

You might also want to consider not using variable names like x,y,z when asking a question about your code.

So, now, I can see where your problem is: you're using ToString on a query, but you probably want the first Caption instead:

```
return (from p in lstProvisions
        group x by x.Name into y
        where y.Count() > 1
        from z in y
        select new FieldConfiguration()
          {
            Name = p.Name,
            ProvisionFieldID = p.ID.ToString(),
            FieldType = Configuration.SyncapayPlus.FieldType.Provision,
            SourceOption = p.OptionValue.ToString(),
            Caption = (from b in benefits
                       where b.Key == p.BenefitID
                       select string.Format("{0}_{1}", b.Value, p.Name)
                      ).First() // perhaps FirstOrDefault() or FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
          }
       ).ToList()
```

Alternatively, if you want a string representation of all benefits, you can use string.Join again instead of First.